# AWS APIGateway Define canary stage in CDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I  define an API Gateway using CDK [Typescript] and can't find how to define the Canary setting by CDK.
my goal is to define the same resources twice with little configure changes one for the stage and for the canary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference in the docs for Canary in the actual restAPI construct - however, as with most things in CDK, you can make use of the CloudFormation escape hatch to manually do so:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.CfnDeployment.html

this Cfn function will replicate the deployment options in CloudFormation Templates for a deployment of an API, and it has a hook for CanaryDeployment

Comment: I ended up using this but instead of replacing the deployment options i add this as 'standalone' resource

Comment: Hi could you share your solution? I trying to do the same but it doesn't work form me. A Canary is created but deployment is either promoted or bypassed in the end. I am patching RestApi.last_deployment with deployment_canary_settings and stage_name

Comment: Stage canary or Deployment canary or both defined has the same effect - no effect at least visible on the ui